How do I properly wire an SL-510-SS pyrgeometer to measure its internal thermistor resistance?
I've acquired an SL-510-SS pyrgeometer and am having trouble wiring the internal thermistor.
The manual gives the following description:


The manual also provides the following diagram:

I've successfully wired the white & black wires to my datalogger (MCR-4V) and get expected outputs from the thermopile.
I attempted to wire the thermistor as follows, but the result is that I don't read any voltage on the datalogger for the thermistor channel:

Power supply positive (+) lead -> pyrgeometer red wire
Pyrgeometer green wire -> datalogger positive (+) input
Pyrgeometer blue wire -> split into two:

one end into datalogger negative (-) input
the other end into power supply negative (-) lead



The result when I give the power supply a 500 mV voltage is no apparent difference on the datalogger input. The power supply indicates 0.000A of output.
I'm hesitant to experiment further as I don't want to break the pyrgeometer, but also am not really sure what else to try.


An excitation voltage of 2.5 V DC is recommended to minimize self-heating and current drain, while still maintaining adequate measurement sensitivity (mV output from thermistor per C). < page 14 of manual https://www.apogeeinstruments.com/content/SL-510-610-manual.pdf
Should not be the power supply ... 2.5 V in place of 0.5 V?


Good Q, it indicates lower can be used. I expected something at the lower value… didn’t want to give it too much to limit damage if I did something wrong !

Good precaution for lower levels of power supply!

The answer, embarrassingly, is that one of my alligator clip connectors was loose .
Once I fixed it, it worked as expected. The wiring was correct. I will leave the question here as a lesson to all.

"Alligators" are always creatures... surprising... :-)
